# Page loads all pages of the image gallery with pagination

Tags: pages, pagination, gallery

Same as [my previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/135178/17929) I have moved to new website. Here there is a page which contains an image gallery with pagination. The text code is like this:

```
[gallery columns="6" ids="318,319,320,321,322,323,324,325,326,327,328,329,330,331,332,333,334,335,336,337,338,340,341,342"]
<!--nextpage-->
[gallery columns="6" ids="343,344,345,346,347,348,349,350,351,352,353,354,355,356,357,358,359,360,361,362,363,364,365,366"]
```

There are about 50 gallery pages in the pagination. It looks like if we load a page, it loads all pages of that gallery page at once (i.e. from 1 to 50). Because loading the page gives me the following error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\mywebsite.com\subdomain\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php on line 1362

In the old website it works fine and loads page within 5-10 seconds. But in the new website even after setting 120 second for execution time it gives an error.

What can be an issue? How can I solve this?

---

#### Update:

Let's don't consider that I have moved the site. What I did is: I created a new page. Added an image gallery. Set pagination. Saved page. Loading the page takes too much time and fails due to maximum execution time. Here problem is not the maximum execution time of 120. The problem is it takes too much time to load instead of 5-10 seconds. FYI(if this may cause this issue): I have installed Jetpack app.

Comment: Let me know if you want the URL of both sites.

Comment: What is in functions.php:1362?

Comment: @kraftner - Actually line number in the error message changes after every refresh.

Comment: Check your server logs, including the MySQL ones.

Comment: @s_ha_dum - Please see the updated question.

Comment: Your edit doesn't tell me where the problem is. For example, it doesn't tell me if the database server is timing out or crashing.